# Power of motor needed to carry 2kg of weight at speed of 10 kmph

Tags: motor, dc-motor, torque, rpm

I need to make rc car which can carry a weight of 1-2 kg and can give speed upto 15kmph, can anyone please tell me what should be rpm and torque of motor for this purpose ?
Thank You !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about mechanical rather than electrical design, and because this is the type of question where you'll be far better off seeking experiential knowledge on an RC hobby site rather than trying to sort things out from first principles - an exercise that almost invariably leads to oversights that would be avoided by including experiential knowledge in the design process.

Comment: high school physics should have taught you about mass and acceleration determines force or torque needed and final velocity gives kinetic energy with some friction losses, while voltage and gear ratio with motor RPM/V yields final velocity with no friction.

Answer (score 3):

The mass considered by itself can not be used to calculate the required power. You must consider friction, the slope of the surface that the vehicle must climb, the rate of acceleration that must be achieved and the aerodynamic drag. There are answers to questions here that cover this in more detail. You should see a list of related question on the right side if the screen when looking at this answer.

Look at **[this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/328572/model-train-working-help)** question.